# NUL file created without reason when perform curl in separate threads from php

Tags: php

HI I want to run a curl request in multiple threads

I am using it as follows :

```
 $cmd ='curl -X POST --data "' . $params . '" "' . $url . '"';

pclose(popen('start /B cmd /C ' .$cmd. ' >NUL 2>NUL', 'r' ));
```

everything is working but the problem is that in my root folder "NUL" file has been cretaed and makes problem in git repository ..etc

thanks

Comment: You should probably use some `escapeshellarg` in there.

Comment: @ccKep . thanks , how do I do that ?